# Integrating $\int \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Integrating $$\int \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
Using substitution of $x=\tan \theta$, I got the required answer. But is there a more *elegant* solution to the problem?

Comment: Which is the measure of elegance? I mean, $x=\tan \theta$ works and is not particularly inelegant...

Comment: You can solve it without substitution - just use complex numbers...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

setting $$t=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$ then we get after squaring $$t^2-x=\sqrt{x^2+1}$$ squaring again and solving for $x$ we get $$x=\frac{t^4-1}{2t^2}$$ and we obtain $$dx=\frac{t^4+1}{t^3}dt$$ and our integral will be
$$\int t^2+\frac{1}{t^2}dt$$

Comment: Very nice substitution!

Answer (score 20):

HINT....You could try $x=\sinh\theta$, because the square root expression simplifies dramatically

Comment: excellent hint!

Answer (score 14):

**HINT**

> $$
> \sqrt{ x + \sqrt{ x^2 + 1 } }
> = \sqrt{ \frac{ x + i }{ 2 } } + \sqrt{ \frac{ x - i }{ 2 } }
> $$

That would be enough simple to solve the integral...

We get

> $$
> \begin{eqnarray}
> \int \sqrt{ x + \sqrt{ x^2 + 1 } } dx
> &=& \int \left\{ \sqrt{ \frac{ x + i }{ 2 } } + \sqrt{ \frac{ x - i }{ 2 } }
>    \right\} d x\\\\
> &=& \frac{4}{3} \left\{ \sqrt{ \frac{ x + i }{ 2 } }^3
>     + \sqrt{ \frac{ x - i }{ 2 } }^3 \right\} \quad \textrm{(*)}\\\\
> &=& \bbox[16px,border:2px solid #800000] {\frac{4}{3} \sqrt{ x + \sqrt{ x^2 + 1 } } \left\{
>     x - \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{x^2+1}\right\}}
> \end{eqnarray}
> $$

(*) Where we have used

> $$
> a^3 + b^3 = \Big( a + b \Big) \Big( a^2 + b^2 - a b \Big)
> $$

Comment: @Dr.MV: The equation in the hint looks good to me. $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+\color{#C00000}{2}ab$

Comment: @Dr.MV: Nope, they are equal, as $( \sqrt{a+b} + \sqrt{a-b} )^2 = 2 a + 2 \sqrt{a^2-b^2}$

Comment: @johannesvalks Yes, it is.  So, a big +1!

Comment: @Dr.MV: Thanks ;)

Comment: @robjohn Yes ... fancy math ... LOL

Answer (score 5):

Let $$ I = \int \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}} \, dx\;,$$ Let $$x+\sqrt{x^2+1} = t^2 \tag 1$$

Then $$ \left(1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right) \, dx = 2t \, dt\Rightarrow t^2 \, dx = 2t\sqrt{x^2+1} \, dt$$

Now using $$\bullet\; \left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\right)\cdot \left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x\right) = 1$$

So we get $$ \sqrt{x^2+1}-x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x} = \frac{1}{t^2} \tag 2$$

Now add $(1)$ and $(2)\;,$ we get $\displaystyle \sqrt{x^2+1} = \frac{t^2+t^{-2}}{2}$

So we get $$ dx = \frac{\left(t^2+t^{-2}\right)\cdot 2t}{2t^2} \, dt$$

so Integral $$\displaystyle I = \int ( t^2+t^{-2}) \, dt = \frac{t^3}{3}-\frac{1}{t}+\mathcal{C}$$